# flaticon not displaying on webpage

Tags: svg, icons, adobe-illustrator, viewbox

I am trying to display a envelope flaticon. I have tried everything and the envelope will not display. I have the following link set up that links to the css file  :

```
http://patskailua.com/font-email/font/flaticon.css
```

The icon that I am trying display is

```
http://www.patskailua.com/font-email/001-interface.svg
```

The directions on the flaticon says to publish it using the following code:

```
<svg class="icon">
```

The website is at:
    http://patskailua.com/div6.html#

I have tried everything and cannot get this icon to display. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Beth

Comment: I think, for better, you should use http://fontawesome.io. try `<span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-envelope-open fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span>`

Comment: That works!  I wish I could get the other one to work, but there is something wrong and I don't know what?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this in HTML page:

```html
<img src="http://www.patskailua.com/font-email/001-interface.svg">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. 
In `http://patskailua.com/font-email/font/flaticon.css`, remove `font-email/font/` from the url of the font. 
The style will look like shown below.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Flaticon";
  src: url("Flaticon.eot");
  src: url("Flaticon.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("Flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
       url("laticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("../svg/001-interface.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```